# Integrate a set of data/Calculus refresher

Tags: calculus

My curiosity was peaked regarding this simple scenario:

I have a set of data (flowrate from a hose) for a given span of time. If I want to find the total volume delivered to a bucket, I would integrate flowrate w.r.t. time. In this case, by lower bound is not 0, but is 4 gpm. How can I set my limits so that I only integrate between the data points and my lower limit of 4? Would this be a double integral w.r.t. to time (x) and flowrate (f(x))?

My thought of what the integrals might look like:

$$\int_{t=0}^{t} f(t) dt - \int_4^{f(t)}\int_{t=0}^{t}f(t) dt = total \ volume $$

*I know I could subtract 4 from all by datapoints and then take the integral from t = 0 to t = end, but I want to know if a double integral is applicable in this situation*

[Graph of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68eOt.png)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter that the flow rate happens to have a minimum of $4$ rather than $0$. You would still just have a volume of
$$\int_{t_0}^{t_1}f(t)\; dt$$ discharged over the time span between $t=t_0$ and $t=t_1$.

On the other hand, if you mean that $f$ measures the amount by which the flow rate exceeds $4$ gpm (so for example $f\approx 0$ on the left end of your graph), then the additional discharge would be the integral above, and you would need to add to it $\int_{t_0}^{t_1}4\; dt $ to obtain a total discharged volume of
$$\int_{t_0}^{t_1}(4+f(t))\; dt$$

Can you clarify what you intend?

Comment: The graph shows the measured flowrate for the time I took the measurements (so beyond the x-axis of the graph f\approx 0 because I have the hose closed). What I am trying to do is figure out the total volume of those times when the flowrates were above 4. It's like I have the hose supplying 4gpm onto my lawn but then when I fill the bucket I turn on a pump.